# are these sets isomorphic?

Tags: order-theory

$\le$ is less-than-or-equal relation.

Is $\langle\Bbb Q\cap((0,1)\cup(4,5)),\le\rangle>$ isomorphic with $\langle\Bbb Q \cap ((0,1)\cup(4,5)\cup\{2,3\},\le\rangle$ ?

They are both totally ordered, countable and none of them has greatest elements or minimum/maximum.

I thought that they are isomorphic but then I heard that they are not. I don't know why.

Comment: Can you find a property that distinguishes $2$ from the other points in the second set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** Show that having an immediate successor is something preserved by isomorphisms.